# NextJs: Dynamic to static error when using generateStaticParams with cookie

Tags: next.js, next.js13, next.js14

I am using Next.js 14 and App Router.

I want to statically render part of a product inventory using generateStaticParams. Rest of the products should be rendered dynamically using dynamicParams=true and dynamic=“auto” in the page.tsx which will render a single product on the screen. There are new products created all the time so it will be impossible to statically render every product even if I would build every 5 minutes, so I have to have a dynamic fallback.

My setup will use fetch to get the products from an api and this operation needs a JWT token which will be fetched from another service using a secret. During build-time the code will generate a token on the fly but in client runtime it will create a token and save it to a cookie and use it during all fetch operations.

After deploy if I navigate to a single product created statically it will work, but navigating to a dynamically created product will fail. The error is “Page changed from static to dynamic at runtime /123456, reason: cookies” However, this product was never to be rendered statically and not listed in the productIds in generateStaticParams.

Is it by design that I cannot use cookies at all if I want to statically render only part of the products and dynamically render the rest?

Currently the code is not even trying to access cookies during build-time and this is being done by separating runtime logics with a conditional built with process.env.NEXT_PHASE === PHASE_PRODUCTION_BUILD.